# CSS Reset On Cross Browsers

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

I have web page with some elements. When I run the page on different browsers the elements are positioned differently. I want the position of elements to be the same in all browsers(Chrome,Firefox,IE,Opera,Safari). I red abaout CSS Reset and created CSS file and I put in it the content from this page http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/ to reset the css configurations. Then I run the page and again it look different in different browsers. What should I do to make the page to look the same in different browsers ?

Comment: give a sample of your code, which looks different on different browsers. you will get help in no time

Comment: It'll be extremely hard to answer without any code or additional infos, like what browsers you mean and what are the differences. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's a rather generic question, so any advice has to be generic too.

1. Use a Doctype that triggers [standards mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) (Quirks mode is inconsistent and you want to avoid it)
2. Test your HTML and CSS with a [markup validator](http://validator.w3.org) and a [CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)
3. Consider using a CSS reset to remove differences between browser default stylesheets
4. Research specific issues you have to learn about browser bugs so you can avoid them in the future

Comment: You explained what I meant by (stick to standards) - Kudos

Answer (score 1):

CSS reset isn't a magical wand that would make your page render the same across different browsers. It's to strip all elements down to the point where they act like a div or a span, visually speaking. That creates a foundation on which authors can build their own stylistic ideas.

So if the CSS you wrote is not rendering the same across the browsers it's not because CSS reset is not working. There are different reasons like lack of support of certain features, browsers' bugs or different implementation ... etc

You should stick to standards and search for workarounds if there's something wrong with a specific browser. Also note that different browsers render web pages differently. That's a fact we have to accept and try not to go overzealous when we code. Sometimes it will never look the exact same!